Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:+] in build.gradle
Hello I am an IT Student. I'm struggling with this error "Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."
How can I Fix this? Can someone pleaseeee helpppppp :<<<
This is my Build.gradle files in APP
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.23' apply false
    
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.care_cove"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.care_cove"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

    compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

and this is my build.gradle file in project or android

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


I tried changing the versions but still did not work

classpath is a configuration available in the dependencies block of the buildscript block. It is available to place dependencies on the classpath of the build script itself.
So it could be you meant to write something like:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
    }
}

I've added a repositories block because you need some kind of source for those dependencies.
As for what exactly the intention and use of these dependencies is, perhaps you should look back at whatever tutorial or example you are following.
